# Widgets are not placed as expected in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I created the custom widget which has buttons in a horizontal layout.

[image]

But buttons are not placed correctly and shrink.

[image]

I can avoid this by setting the button size manually.
Is there any way to avoid this behavior automatically?

.ui XML code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>VideoPlaybackWidgetBase</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="VideoPlaybackWidgetBase">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>790</width>
    <height>58</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
    <horstretch>1</horstretch>
    <verstretch>1</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>16777215</width>
    <height>58</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
   <item>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="horizontalFrame">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="moveFirstButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="movePrevButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="playButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="moveNextButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="moveLastButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Try changing size policies of the buttons. Note that "maximum" means "not bigger than", basically opposite of "maximize".

Comment: I modified the size policy of button, but nothing happend. Here is [a full XML UI file](https://gist.github.com/Licht-T/407fdc7658f35cc24d97).

Comment: @LichtTakeuchi. I cannot reproduce this. What platform are you on, and how are you testing the ui file? Are you using Preview in Qt Designer?

Answer (score 0):

I see `Maximum` size policy in the XML. Go to buttons' properties in Designer, and change size policy for example to `Expanding`. Also make sure the button widths are same (or with the right ratio if you want different width buttons).

Alternatively, you can keep the `Maximum` policy and just increase the width to what ever you want to be the maximum button width, like 2000 to allow for 10000 pixel wide future displays... There are many ways to achieve desired sizing behavior. Choose what best describes what you want, in this case perhaps `MinimumExpanding`.

See [`QSizePolicy` docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum).